# Help me see the connection between exponential functions and quadratic curves

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, quadratics, parametrization

We know that the degree 2 equations $x^2 + y^2 =1$ and $x^2 - y^2 =1$ can be parametrized by exponential functions. How come exponential functions show up in this seemingly unrelated area? I think it has to do with the fact that exponential functions satisfy $y'=y$, while the degree 2 equations satisfy $y'=\frac{-x}{y}$ and $y'=\frac{x}{y}$ respectively.

Also, there are two extreme cases of degree two equations- parabola and straight lines. Exponential functions don't show up in those. What exactly happens as we approach those extreme cases which causes the exponential behavior to collapse?

Can degree 3 or higher curves be parametrized by exponentials? $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is also a hyperbola. Can exponentials parametrize that?

Comment: Good question. Partial answer. trigonometric functions (which are exponentials with complex exponents) show up for the circle because $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ expresses the conservation of energy for the second order differential equation $f" + f = 0$ when you think of that equation as modeling an oscillator.

Comment: Partial answer for your last question: Only singular degree-3 curves can be parametrized (with elementary functions). For instance, the singular elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+2x^2+x$ can be parametrized using polynomial functions. For general cubic curves, you can use the elliptic functions, which are basically trigonometric functions for ellipses.

Comment: Straight lines can be parameterized with exponential functions.

Comment: If $\{(x,y): x^2-y^2=2\}$ $=  \{(f(t),g(t)): t\in T\}$ for some suitable $f,g,T$ then $\{(x,y):xy=1\}=$ $=\{(\, (f(t)-g(t))/\sqrt 2\,,(f(t)+g(t))/\sqrt 2\;):t\in T\}.$

Comment: "$y=1/x$ is also a hyperbola. Can exponentials parametrize that?" - yes: $y=e^t$, $x=e^{-t}$. Then the hyperbole $x^2 - y^2 =1$ can be obtained from $y=1/x$ by a rotation through angle $\pi/4$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit exactly which parametric equation of circle you are referring to ? Because in my understanding if you allow complex numbers then $cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are expressible as exponentials and all conic sections are expressible in $$r = \frac{e.p}{1+\pm e cos(\theta)}$$